# Making a Shader output into a face attribute in python

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, texture-baking

is there a way to turn the average color of the faces of an object into an attribute with python ?

Maybe this has to do with texture baking, i honestly don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could bake to vertex color, then convert to the face domain, which would average the color at the corners.

Comment: thank you that's an interesting approach, i'll try it out